# How to access a variable value from a method to another method?

Tags: java, android

I need access `String items` inside `onOptionsItemSelected` I declared the `String items` globally inside the class and I can access the variable inside `onOptionsItemSelected` but I get null as a value. My problem is inside

```
 case R.id.share_note:
 Share.shareNote(this, items);
```

When I share the text I get null. I tried and searched on SO a lot but in vain because in my case it is a little different.

```
public class AddChecklists extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
Button btnAddItem;
public LinearLayout linearLayout;
DbHelper dbHelper;
String items;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_checklist);

    Toast.makeText(this, "problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    btnAddItem = findViewById(R.id.btn_add_item);
    linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);

    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);

    // this handler auto clicks btnAddItem button after the provided time;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            btnAddItem.performClick();
        }
    },100);

    btnAddItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addView();
        }
    });
}

public  void addView(){

    View checklistView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.checklist_view, null, false);
    EditText etChecklistItem = checklistView.findViewById(R.id.et_checklist_item);
    CheckBox checkBox = checklistView.findViewById(R.id.check_box);


    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if(b)
                etChecklistItem.setText(strikeThrough(etChecklistItem.getText().toString()));
                //  state = true;
            else
                etChecklistItem.setText(etChecklistItem.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    // This method makes the Action Button add new checkbox instead of press the BtnAdd every time but
    // the editText must have imeOptions="actionDone in XML file
    etChecklistItem.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                btnAddItem.performClick();
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    });

    etChecklistItem.requestFocus();
    linearLayout.addView(checklistView);

    // this handler makes the keyboard to popup on the Edittext and also
    // the editText must requestFocus();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(etChecklistItem, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    },200);

    ImageView imgDelete = checklistView.findViewById(R.id.img_delete);

    imgDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            removeView(checklistView);
        }
    });


}

public void removeView(View view){
    linearLayout.removeView(view);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.save_delete_share, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            saveChecklist();
            return true;

        case R.id.btn_save:

            saveChecklist();
            break;

        case R.id.btn_delete:

            //not yet implemented
            Toast.makeText(this, "delete button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.share_note:
            Share.shareNote(this, items);

    }
    return true;
}

public void saveChecklist(){

    Intent intent = new Intent();

    ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> statusList = new ArrayList<>();
    String status;

    for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
        EditText etChecklistItem = v.findViewById(R.id.et_checklist_item);
        CheckBox checkBox = v.findViewById(R.id.check_box);

        if (checkBox.isChecked())
            status = "1";

        else
            status = "0";

        if(etChecklistItem.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            etChecklistItem.setText(null);
        itemList.add(etChecklistItem.getText().toString());
        statusList.add(status);


    }

    StringBuilder stringBuilderItem = new StringBuilder();
    for(String singleItem: itemList) {
        stringBuilderItem.append(singleItem);
        stringBuilderItem.append("\n");
    }

    items =  stringBuilderItem.toString();


    StringBuilder stringBuilderStatus = new StringBuilder();
    for(String singleStatus: statusList){
        stringBuilderStatus.append(singleStatus);
        stringBuilderStatus.append("\n");
    }

    String statuses = stringBuilderStatus.toString();

    dbHelper.insertChecklist(statuses, items, DateTime.date(), DateTime.time(), System.currentTimeMillis());

    setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Checklist saved...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //  new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> finish(), 500);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    super.onBackPressed();
    saveChecklist();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}

public SpannableString strikeThrough(String txt){

    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(txt);
    StrikethroughSpan strikethroughSpan = new StrikethroughSpan();
    spannableString.setSpan(strikethroughSpan,0, txt.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return spannableString;

  }
}
```

Comment: Evidently you're trying to use the value before it was ever set.  Are you sure `saveChecklist` has ever been called?

Comment: Take a look at this line  items =  stringBuilderItem.toString(); by the way I am looking for a solution. Any idea?

Comment: @accessviolation already gave you an idea. There is absolutely ***no*** guarantee in your code that saveChecklist is being called before the String in question is being accessed. Please re-read access's comment.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

That's a solution for After many tries I could rearrange the code and it gots working.

```
public class AddChecklist extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
Button btnAddItem;
public LinearLayout linearLayout;
DbHelper dbHelper;
String items;
ArrayList<String> itemList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_checklist);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    btnAddItem = findViewById(R.id.btn_add_item);
    linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);

    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);

    itemList = new ArrayList<>();

    // this handler auto clicks btnAddItem button after the provided time;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            btnAddItem.performClick();
        }
    },100);

    btnAddItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addView();

            }
    });
}

public  void addView(){

    View checklistView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.checklist_view, null, false);
    EditText etChecklistItem = checklistView.findViewById(R.id.et_checklist_item);
    CheckBox checkBox = checklistView.findViewById(R.id.check_box);


    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if(b)
                etChecklistItem.setText(strikeThrough(etChecklistItem.getText().toString()));
          //  state = true;
            else
                etChecklistItem.setText(etChecklistItem.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    // This method makes the Action Button add new checkbox instead of press the BtnAdd every time but
    // the editText must have imeOptions="actionDone in XML file
    etChecklistItem.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                btnAddItem.performClick();
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    });

    etChecklistItem.requestFocus();
    linearLayout.addView(checklistView);

    // this handler makes the keyboard to popup on the Edittext and also
    // the editText must requestFocus();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(etChecklistItem, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    },200);

    ImageView imgDelete = checklistView.findViewById(R.id.img_delete);

    imgDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            removeView(checklistView);
        }
    });


}

public void removeView(View view){
    linearLayout.removeView(view);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.save_delete_share, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            saveChecklist();
            return true;

        case R.id.btn_save:

            saveChecklist();
           break;

        case R.id.btn_delete:

            deleteChecklist();
            break;

        case R.id.share_note:

           shareNote();


    }
    return true;
}

public void saveChecklist(){

    Intent intent = new Intent();

    ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> statusList = new ArrayList<>();
    String status;

    for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
        EditText etChecklistItem = v.findViewById(R.id.et_checklist_item);
        CheckBox checkBox = v.findViewById(R.id.check_box);

        if (checkBox.isChecked())
            status = "1";

        else
            status = "0";

        if(etChecklistItem.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            etChecklistItem.setText(null);
        itemList.add(etChecklistItem.getText().toString());
        statusList.add(status);


    }

    StringBuilder stringBuilderItem = new StringBuilder();
    for(String singleItem: itemList) {
        stringBuilderItem.append(singleItem);
        stringBuilderItem.append("\n");
    }

    items =  stringBuilderItem.toString();


    StringBuilder stringBuilderStatus = new StringBuilder();
    for(String singleStatus: statusList){
        stringBuilderStatus.append(singleStatus);
        stringBuilderStatus.append("\n");
    }

    String statuses = stringBuilderStatus.toString();

    dbHelper.insertChecklist(statuses, items, DateTime.date(), DateTime.time(), System.currentTimeMillis());

    setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Checklist saved...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //  new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> finish(), 500);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    super.onBackPressed();
    saveChecklist();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}

public SpannableString strikeThrough(String txt){

    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(txt);
    StrikethroughSpan strikethroughSpan = new StrikethroughSpan();
    spannableString.setSpan(strikethroughSpan,0, txt.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return spannableString;

}

public void deleteChecklist(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Delete Checklist");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checklist deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

public void shareNote(){
    ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
        EditText etChecklistItem = v.findViewById(R.id.et_checklist_item);

        itemList.add(etChecklistItem.getText().toString());

    }

    StringBuilder stringBuilderItem = new StringBuilder();
    for(String singleItem: itemList) {
        stringBuilderItem.append(singleItem);
        stringBuilderItem.append("\n");
    }

    items =  stringBuilderItem.toString();


    Share.shareNote(this, items);
}
```

}